# Add state value to class name of elements created in method

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I have a button, on click it calls a method. The method creates some elements from an array:

```
let output = [1, 2, 3].map((value, index) =>
     <span key={index}>
       {value}
     </span>
);
```

These elements are inserted into the dom by changing the state from the method:

```
this.setState({
  inputTextContainer: output
})
```

and having the state value in the render():

```
{inputTextContainer}
```

My question is can I add classes to the span elements that change when the state changes? Something like the following:

```
let output = [1, 2, 3].map((value, index) =>
     <span key={index} className={example}>
       {value}
     </span>
);
```

The problem with this is that it adds the className, but doesn't update on state change.

Comment: create another method, say `this.getClassName()` inside the component. Have it return class names according to state.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array of objects in your state.

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
     values: [{
           value: 1,
           className: 'example'
        },{
           value: 2,
           className: 'anotherOne'
        }
     ]}
  )}
}
```

and in render() put something like:

```
render(){
    <div>
         {this.state.values.map((obj, index) => 
            <span key={index} className={obj.className}>
               {obj.value}
            </span>
         )}
    </div>
}
```